# Floating Data Grid in WPF c#

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datagrid

i want to create a floating datagrid. initially on stratup of application the grid will be a part of main WPF window but when user will double click on the datagrid. it will be detached from the main window and user can place it any where on the screen. latter on when user will again double click on the detached datagrid it will again become part of main wpf window

can anyone please give me some guidlines or piece of code in order to implement this idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://avalondock.codeplex.com/ is a docking manager that can help you accomplish this and more. You may need to customize it for the 'double-click' behaviour since this is not really a standard UI interaction.

Comment: thanx but it creats tabs but i dont want it like a tab my datagrid is a part of wpf window but it will be separated when i ll double click on it

Comment: There are several kinds of 'dock' available with avalon, the tool-window-like dock actually does not have a tab. Either way, good luck.

Comment: can you please exactly tell this dock name